# How to properly type check nested records allowing partial subtrees with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

Please have a look at the following demo.
`interface Data` defines a schema for nested data.
`function check` shall validate whether a given partial subtree of this `Data` structure is fine and throw a compile-time error if not (hopefully with a more or less detailed and understandable error message and not just "... is not assignable to type 'never").

```
interface Data {
  namespace1: {
    keyA: string,
    keyB: string
  },

  namespace2: {
    keyC: string,
    keyD: string
  }
}

// This function's only purpose is to perform a compile-time check
// whether the given partial data is valid.
// Returns the first and only argument in case of success,
// otherwise a compile-time error will occur.
function check<??>(
  partialData: ????
): ?????? {
  return partialData
}

// Example 1 => okay
const validPartialData1 = check({
  namespace1: {
    keyB: 'b'
  }
})

// Example 2 => okay
const validPartialData2 = check({
  namespace1: {
    keyB: 'b'
  },

  namespace2: {
    keyC: 'c'
  }
})

// Example 3 => okay
const validPartialData3 = check({})

// Example 4 => compile-time error!
const invalidPartialData1 = check({
  namespace1: {
    keyC: 'c'
  }
})

// Example 5 => compile-time error!
const invalidPartialData2 = check({
  xyz: {
    keyA: 'a'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `check` function. Use optional field directly.

```
interface Data {
  namespace1?: {
    keyA?: string,
    keyB?: string
  },

  namespace2?: {
    keyC?: string,
    keyD?: string
  }
}

const validPartialData1:Data = {
  namespace1: {
    keyB: 'b'
  }
}
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true&ts=4.5.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5EOAWwgGcAHRCARgH4AuHfA5AawgE8BBR5MsFFABzADQsCHTgCE%20AoSGEsAvuJZFSlagCY%20eVuy4BhOYJHiDU1KYVKCy3A9wB6Z8gCiADxIUANihpkAF4APmQAezY4TlwEcJABZAA3OF9gABMABTgoMGBU9EwaBkKsIOYCDXIqJGKK1ilpJgByACNmlUdcFzcvH39kbWCwyOjY%20MSUtKycvIKMOG0SheD6qq1apn0GribkNo77NUqSap0tiUNOIxaEQ%20QHJ1cPb2I-FABmYYiomLiEsDJVIZbK5fK%20UofZaYVbYJ69V7vZAAFm%20cTewH8AFo8qRkNAoOEoABCcYA5CgKYg2bg0rFUqw9SnDa0C6WYy3e6PbrPPpvAYAVjR4Qx2NxKAJRNJ-0SlOBMzB80wSwZ5W2nk4AC82TseC04FzHEA)

If you don't want to change `Data` type. You can define another `PartialData`

```
type NestPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: NestPartial<T[P]>;
}
type PartialData = NestPartial<Data>

const validPartialData1: PartialData = {
    namespace1: {
        keyB: 'b'
    }
}
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true&ts=4.5.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5EOAWwgGcAHRCARgC4d9CWBrCATwEFHywpQAcwA0zFgXYcAQr35CxyAL6iFxMlRoAmRnnGFJAYVkCQIhW06pj8lotx3cYDpRQA5CmAAKcKGGBwAGwAeABUAPmQAXiYWAG1PZFBkSQB7GGQQgF0AfkZ3Pm9ff2CQ%20MywgG57R2cUQr9A9Ewo5HyvHwbgprgw3FwAen7kAFEAD1JKAJRaKIiU1jgOXAQUkD5kADdA4AATeuLuhmR9xowsaN1CNQpqJCPLvUkZZAByACMXhTsHQZHxkkmKE0s2Q80Wy1W6y2AV2JwC3W0xw6BzOLQeRFINxo93M%20k4z3en1sKhY1w0SER6IsHCMrwQRMI3z6vzGEymyAAzCCwUsVmswJttntkadMBzGHDumifkNWQD2QAWEErAHAKYAWj8ZGQ0CgKSgAEIIfzEiBobCRfCzkdJaiLqpMeS6DpcRJOLSXvSvtUBrL-oDkABWZUpVUarUoXX6o189agc3CoqiuCI23Ne0sUYcABeLr0bu4jBecAZBG%20QA)